# How to explain peak in training history of a convolutional neural network?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, training, accuracy, loss

I am training a simple convolutional neural network to recognize two types of 1024-point frequency spectra (FFT). This is the model I'm using:

```
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=LeakyReLU(), input_shape=(nInput,1)))
cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=LeakyReLU()))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(nFinalDense, activation=LeakyReLU()))
cnn.add(Dense(nOutput, activation='sigmoid'))
```

However I get the following accuracy and loss during training:
[image]

Why do I get the large peak in both plots? How can it be explained? Is there a problem with the data I'm using (I mention that I obtain a similar peak when training an autoencoder for denoising using the same data)?

Comment: Are you getting it multiple times assuming you have randomly initialized weights Everytime or is it a one time thing?

Comment: @DuttaA I get it multiple times. I'm using Tensorflow to train the model with default weight initializers for each layer, so it automatically randomizes the weights. I mention that I set the seed values for numpy and tensorflow at the beginning of the script to get a more deterministic output. I've changed the seed value and I get a smaller peak at a different epoch. What do you think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the peak was caused by the data I am using. Specifically, the MinMaxScaler changed the data shape and I resolved the issue by simply dividing to the max value.